# Kafka Tombstoning with a DSL KStream to KTable Transformation

Tags: java, kotlin, apache-kafka-streams

I have a `KStream<String, X>` which I essentially want to convert to a `KTable<String, Y>`

The only way I could find to achieve this using the DSL is with a map, group then reduce.

```
val stream: KStream<String, X> = ...
val table: KTable<String, Y> = stream
  .mapValues({ value -> toYOrNull(value)})
  .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.String(), ySerde))
  .reduce(
    {old: Y?, updated: Y? -> updated},
    Materialized.`as`<String, Y, KeyValueStore<Bytes, ByteArray>>("y-store")
      .withKeySerde(Serdes.String()
      .withValueSerde(ySerde)
  )
```

I would expect this to handle the case when the value of `updated` in the `reduce` is `null` however when I inspect the store using the `TopologyTestDriver` it still seems to have the old version. What am I doing wrong?

This is my test:

```
@Test
fun shouldDeleteFromTableWhenNull() {
  val store = testDriver.getKeyValueStore<String, Y?>("y-store")
  store.put("key", Y())

  inputTopic.pipeInput("key", anXThatMapsToANullY)

  assertThat(store.get("key")).isNull() // Fails as the old entry is still there
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Records with value null are ignored.

It is expected behaviour according to documentation: [KGroupedStream::reduce(...) Java Doc](https://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KGroupedStream.html#reduce-org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Reducer-)

> Combine the values of records in this stream by the grouped key. Records with null key **or value are ignored**

Answer (score 1):

In upcoming Apache Kafka 2.5 release a new operator `KStream#toTable()` is added to address this use case (cf. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7658)

In older versions, you would need to use a non-null "surrogate delete value" to avoid that the record is dropped and let your reduce function return `null` if it sees the "surrogate delete value".

Comment: Thanks for the response, do you have any idea when that will be released?

Comment: The release plan can be found in the Apache Kafka wiki: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=143428858 -- devlopment is closed and voting on RCs started already. Hence, it should be release soon assuming no more blockers are found during testing.

Comment: @Eduardo in older version, you can also using transformValues to access and update store `y-store` directly by getting a `KeyValueStore` using `ProcessorContext`

Comment: @TuyenLuong You can do that, but you don't get a `KTable` back -- thus it depends what other operations you want to perform -- for "interactive queries" your suggestion would work. However, if you want to process the data further, for example in a table-table or stream-table join, using `transformValues()` won't help.